# Parallelismus in "Wer ..., der ..."-Sätze

Tags: usage, style, parallelism

Aus dem Spiegel-Magazin:

> Tatsächlich aber hatten sich die Wähler mit ihrem Votum weiterer Gängelung durch jedwede Obrigkeit entzogen. **Wer** ihnen eine reformierte DDR predigte und sie damit einem neuen politischen Großexperiment aussetzen wollte, **wurde** am 18. März 1990 abgestraft. **Wer** ihnen hingegen den schnellen Anschluss an ein bewährtes Demokratiemodell versprach, nämlich die Bundesrepublik samt der so erfolgreichen Westmark, **der wurde honoriert.**

Meinem Verständnis nach sind beide Formen

> Wer ..., wurde ...

und

> Wer ..., der wurde ...

richtig.

Aber gilt es als guter Stil, wenn man die beiden Formen direkt nacheinander benutzt und damit auf den Parallelismus verzichtet? Was wären Gründe dafür? Damit es ein bisschen mehr Variation gibt?

Comment: Ich verstehe hier das "der" als betonend und damit den Gegensatz heraushebend. Stilistisch meiner Meinung nach völlig in Ordnung.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Du hast Recht – beide Formen sind richtig. Die Variante mit "der" betont aber das Subjekt stärker, und da sie am Ende des Abschnitts eingesetzt wird, ergibt das eine (gewollte) Steigerung für die ganze Gedankenkette. Würde man auch an der ersten Stelle schon "der wurde" schreiben, entfiele diese Steigerung. Außerdem würde man die Wiederholung der gleichen Konstruktion eher als langweilig empfinden.